# Attribute doesnt change inside ShadowDOM

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, shadow-dom

In my following code a change of the value doesnt update the input value: Why?

```
class textfield extends HTMLElement {

    get value()
    {
        return this.getAttribute("value");
    }

    set value(val)
    {
        this.setAttribute('value', val);
    }

    get readonly() {
        return this.hasAttribute("readonly");
    }

    set readonly(val)
    {
        if (val)
        {
            this.setAttribute("readonly", '');
        }
        else
        {
            this.removeAttribute("readonly");
        }
    }

    static get observedAttributes() {
        return ['readonly', 'value'];
    }

    attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
        console.log(name, newValue) ;
    }

    constructor()
    {
        super();
        this.attachShadow({ "mode": "open" });
    }

    connectedCallback()
    {
        this.shadowRoot.innerHTML =  
        /*html*/`
        <div>
            <div>
                Lable
            </div>
            <div>
                <input id="vi-input" type="text" value="${this.getAttribute("value")}" ${ this.hasAttribute("readonly") ? "readonly" : "" } />
            </div>
            <div>
                <span>Error</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        `;
    }
}

window.customElements.define("vi-textfield", textfield);
```

And in my index.html:

```
.... 
        <vi-textfield id="myInput" value="2" validation="^\d{4}$" ></vi-textfield>
....
```

When I update it by JS, lets say by:

```
document.getElementById("myInput").value = 3;
```

there will be the given console.log of attributeChangedCallback but the value itself doesnt change....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `input` doesn't update because they are 2 different elements.

```
 set value(val) {
   this.setAttribute('value', val);
 }
```

sets the `value` attribute on

`<vi-textfield value="[val]">`

**not** the `value` attribute on

```
<input id="vi-input" type="text" value="${this.getAttribute("value")}"/>
```

which is **another** element in your elements shadowDOM

`value="${this.getAttribute("value")}"` runs **once**, because `connectedCallback()` runs **once**

If you want to set **both**, you can do:

```
 set value(val) {
   this.setAttribute('value', val);
   this.shadowRoot.getElementById("vi-input").setAttribute("value", val);
 }
```

If you want them in sync, you also need setAttribute code for when `value` on the input changes.

PS.

```
set readonly(val) {
        if (val) {
            this.setAttribute("readonly", '');
        } else {
            this.removeAttribute("readonly");
        }
    }
```

can be written as:

```
set readonly(val) {
        this.toggleAttribute("readonly", val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are setting the value, but not doing anything after that, at least not to the input field.. Your element `vi-textfield` actually is updated if you have a look at your elements tab using your browser's developer tools. You might be able to rebuild your html for example after setting the value by calling

```
this.connectedCallback();
```

To make sure the input field contains the updated value as well.
Or you need to find a way to select and update the input field separately. Or just recall the `connectedCallback()` method like I mentioned.

Or you could add some kind of MutationObserver to your class (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), but I don't think this should work out of the box what you might have thought: while updating the value of the host, update the shadow elements.